# UIScrollView hangs while loading images into UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, performance

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled. All the images were loaded at the start and added to the UIImageViews, but I had a memory-issue as it were more images, so I decided to load the after next image while scrolling if the image isn't set yet. If i get a memory warning, I remove all images except of the current.

The problem is, that the scrollview hangs for a few milliseconds if I scroll.

I'm using

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path/to/image.png"];
```

to load the images. If I use the method imageWithContentsOfFile, it cost alot more time.

Is there a way to show a pixelated image like in the default Photoapp until it's fully loaded?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIImage imageNamed:]
```

caches images for you, so that's why it's better than imageWithContentsOfFile. Since these images are displayed in a table cell, presumably they don't need to be that large. What are the images dimensions on the file system? If you just put the UIImage in a UIImageView and depend on that for scaling, my guess is the scaling happens while you scroll. Can you create thumbnails for each image on the file system and use those?

Comment: The images are displayed in a UIScrollView. The resolution of the images is 960x480 (iphone 4 res) and is downscaled. I thought it is easier to use one image except of adding a second one with @2x for iphone 4. Creating thumbnails would cost alot of time for me I think. Is there no other way?

Comment: if you are depending on UIImageView to scale your images, then you are effectively creating thumbnails in memory anyway. You don't want that happening while you are scrolling. I'd try to find some other time to do this, such as application startup. Regarding the pixelated image load, I don't know of any magic way to do this. Create a low-res version of the image and load that first, then fade in the high-res. The low-res version could simply be the thumbnail scaled up.